# Butterflied Strings Shortest Character Solution

Tags: string-manipulation

The shortest character solution for [Butterflied Strings](https://challenges.wolframcloud.com/challenge/butterflied-strings) on Wolfram Challenges according to the `CODE CHARACTERS` functionality is 40. I have a solution with 42 characters, namely `ButterflyString@x_:= x~~StringReverse@x`

As a reminder, the `CODE CHARACTERS` functionality is "Number of Characters Appearing in the InputForm of the code"

However, I can't reduce it to 40. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to the CodeCharacters on Wolfram Challenges, it's 105 characters long. I should've specified, I'm looking for the shortest solution according to CodeCharacters, which takes the "InputForm" of the function.

Comment: Where can I find the definition of `CodeCharacters`? Or is it just the length of the `InputForm`? or the `FullForm`?

Comment: You can run the tests on WolframChallenges, (https://challenges.wolframcloud.com/challenge/butterflied-strings). It says that the CodeCharacters is the "Number of characters appearing in the InputForm of the code", but it's a bit unclear what that means.

Comment: @Navvye, the InputForm of your code is `ButterflyString[x_] := x~~StringReverse[x]`, which has 42 characters.

Comment: Yes but how'd you figure that out? Why isn't the InputForm just ```ButterflyString@x_:= x~~StringReverse@x```

Comment: InputForm is not the "thing you type into a notebook". It is a particular canonical textual representation, which you can get by using [`InputForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html). For example: `ToString[
 Unevaluated[InputForm[ButterflyString@x_:=x~~StringReverse@x]]]`, then `StringLength[%]`.

Comment: This is really embarrassing that they are not able to state the rules clearly and  unambiguously. Saying "Number of characters appearing in the InputForm of the code" is so vague - should I understand it like "appearing to someone`s eyes"?

Comment: How would they judge a code like, say, `2         3` which outputs `6`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan There is "appearing" lots of space characters :-D

Comment: @azerbajdzan, there is nothing embarassing and nothing ambiguous, really. The `InputForm` of your code is `2*3`, which has exactly 3 characters. Again, `InputForm` is **not** the same thing as the text you type into a notebook!

Comment: @Domen: Sorry, but you seem to miss the thing that output of `InputForm` is not a string hence you can not objectively judge how many characters it has. In your code in your previous comment with `ToString` and `Unevaluated` do you recognize that the output of `ToString` is not the same as output of `InputForm`? `ToString` adds or removes space characters in code differently than it does `InputForm`. So your code is ambiguous too.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, [`InputForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) is a one-dimensional notation; it is not `String` in the Mathematica sense, but it is certainly a string in a broader, computer programming sense, e.g. a _sequence of characters_. I [don't see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTmtb.png) any space adding or removing of by `ToString`, so I am not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Domen: [Simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJOED.png). `ToString` adds one space character and thinks the input code is of length `5` but if you look at the output of `InputForm` itself and select it with mouse you see there is no space at the end of the `InputForm` hence its true length is `4` not `5` as your code suggests.

Comment: Fair enough, my code does not faithfully reproduce the string representation of `InputForm`, but the overall argument and unambiguousness still stand: Wolfram Challenge counts the characters in the `InputForm`, which this case is `4`.

Comment: @Dome: Really? So how do they do it? They have a person there that counts the characters by sight? I guess no. What I guess they have some similar code like yours that is unreliable. Submitting myself a code that they [mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AMdZ.png) as of length `28` I can definitely confirm they judging code is somehow dubious/fishy.

Comment: There is no need to be sarcastic. I don't _know_ how they do it. But that doesn't mean the definition is ambiguous. You still haven't given a single example where there is a discrepancy. Please show what code you submitted that you think is not of length 28.

Comment: @Domen: I have already given you an example, just look four comments above. They fail on my example just like your code fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151655/discussion-between-domen-and-azerbajdzan).